# What exactly is the `/etc/net` project?

Tags: networking, iproute, altlinux

I was reading about iproute2 [here](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) and I saw the following sentence:

> The /etc/net project aims to support most modern network technologies, as it doesn't use ifconfig and allows a system administrator to make use of all iproute2 features, including traffic control.

The [link provided](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/etcnet) points to multiple pages with some configuration examples. From those examples I infer that the `/etc/net` project is mostly a set of conventions about files inside the `/etc/net` directory to store and manage network configuration.

After some googling I found what it seems to be the [official website](https://en.altlinux.org/Etcnet) of the project (in russian but with an english translation). The project was created and is maintained by the team behind yet another linux distribution called Alt Linux.

So far this is what I know... but I have questions...

- Is the project abandoned? Did it ever gain any traction? Why is the Linux Foundation wiki mentioning it as if it is a big deal?
- What is exactly the problem that the project intended to solve? Is that problem solved now by another more successful project?

Comment: The [link to Freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/projects/etcnet/) there was last archived by the Wayback machine in 2016, at which time it was redirecting to http://web.archive.org/web/20160122073759/http://freecode.com/projects/etcnet/, where you can see that the last update was in 2011. I'd say it's safe to say it has been abandoned for a decade. I don't know what the problem it was trying to solve, but netplan and systemd-networkd are probably somewhere in the same problem space.

Comment: Looks like it survived in ALT Linux: https://en.altlinux.org/Etcnet , http://git.altlinux.org/gears/e/etcnet.git which references the original author as pilot, just like in a Wayback machine snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20060426063856/http://freshmeat.net/projects/etcnet/